# Query Is not Running

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

MUTANT TABLE DOES NOT EXIST.MY QUERY IS WORKING FINE BUT WHEN I AM TRYING TO PUT THE RESULT IN A NEW TABLE WHICH DOESN'T EXIST,IT IS SHOWING SOME ERROR.

```
select 
   'Ordinary' , 
   pincode , 
   year ( Date_val ), 
   MONTH ( Date_val ), 
   (100 - cast ( Arr_8 as int )/ cast ( Arr_5 as int )* 100 )
into mutant
from 
( 
   select * from arrow_29june_2010 union all
   select * from arrow_dtp_upg_2009 
) A
where 
   cast ( arr_5 as int )<> 0
```

Comment: Please don't shout. My baby is asleep.

Comment: Please list the error you are receiving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to name columns in select in order to insert them into new table:

```
select 'Ordinary' Ordinary, pincode , year ( Date_val ) Year, MONTH ( Date_val ) Month, (100 - cast ( Arr_8 as int )/ cast ( Arr_5 as int )* 100 ) Something
into mutant

from ( select * from arrow_29june_2010 union all

select * from arrow_dtp_upg_2009 ) A

where cast ( arr_5 as int )<> 0
```

EDIT: forgot to alias 'Ordinary'

Comment: You mean to say that i have to give a Unique name to each column in the select list.  Example-pincode as 'PIN',year(Date_val) as 'DT'

Comment: but yesterday when i had done select first_name,last_name from emp work fine for me .Canyou plz tell me what is the reason i have to alias cloumn name in my new query.

Comment: @manojkumarsingh - You only need to alias the columns that are calculated (how does SQL Server know what `year ( Date_val )` should be called in the new table?) or that would cause a duplicated column name in the new table.

Comment: You have expressions - year(date) etc. Expressions need names, simple column selects do not.

Comment: I have given name to column now(ALIAS) also but i don't still why it is showing error.

Comment: What is the error message? Could you list it in your question? Oh, maybe you forgot to name 'Ordinary'?

Comment: ya,thats was the actual problem.Really appreciate your work...